# How do I convert this double foreach loop to just lambdas?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, foreach

Is this there a way to these foreach loops just **one** lambda expression?

```
    private int getNextEventId()
    {
        int numOfEvents = 0;

        foreach (MonthModel eventMonth in eventsForAllMonths)
        {
            foreach (DayModel eventDay in eventMonth.AllDays)
            {
                numOfEvents += eventDay.CalEvents.Count;
            }
        }

        return numOfEvents + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Have you intentionally said 'just ONE lambda'?  Nobody provided 'just ONE' answer...

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. But it seems alot of people understood what I was asking :)

Comment: You said ONE lambda, that means one =>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int numOfEvents = eventsForAllMonths.SelectMany(m => m.AllDays)
                                    .Select(d => d.CalEvents.Count)
                                    .Sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return (eventsForAllMonths.SelectMany(eventMonth => eventMonth.AllDays).Sum(eventDay => eventDay.CalEvents.Count) + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    private int getNextEventId()
    {
        int numOfEvents = eventsForAllMonths.SelectMany(eventMonth => eventMonth.AllDays).Aggregate(0, (current, eventDay) => current + eventDay.CalEvents.Count);

        return numOfEvents + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
return
    (from m in eventsForAllMonths
    from d in m.AllDays
    select d.CalEvents.Count).Sum() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I `ForEach()` for a living, so:

```
eventsForallMonths.ForEach(em=>em.ForEach(ed=>numOfEvents+=ed.CalEvents.Count));
```

Comment: and `eventsForAllMonths` may not be `List`

Comment: This may or may not work depending on the type of eventsForAllMonths. ForEach is only available to List<T>. If eventsForAllMonths is anything else, this fails.

Comment: It seems icky to me to modify state like that in a lambda.

Comment: I can't believe that someone -1 me :) OP wanted LAMBDAS, and you push him into Extension methods.  tsk tsk

Comment: eventsForAllMonths is a static List. It's just for tests.

Comment: @KirkWoll yeah, but as I said, I foreach() for a living, it works OK

Answer (score 0):

How about transforming this in lambda?

```
List<Item> listItem = new List<Item>();
foreach (StackPanel sp in spPhotos.Children)
{
    foreach(Item item in sp.Children)
    {
        listItem.Add(item);
    }
    sp.Children.Clear();
}
spPhotos.Children.Clear();
```